# here is problem for installing the styled-components from npm?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, styled-components

here is problem installing styled-components with npm install. please anyone help for the same or anyother way for install styled-components
I used command:
npm i styled-components -g
But it is not working for me
so please is here anyother way for same and why is not installing for me what can be problem.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. the `-g` means you are trying to install the package globally which doesn't make much sense if you are building a project. and if somehow you need to install it globally, you might have a permission problem. you *can* do `sudo npm i -g styled-components` but you really shouldn't.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please remove node modules and try installing the same again using yarn this time?

If it is still not working please add more info about your question.

Answer (score 0):

I use the command without the -g and it works for me.

```
npm i styled-components
```

Answer (score 0):

The "npm install styled-components" works fine... just change the directory to the name of your react-app. for instance, if the name of your react app is "my-project", just type "cd my-project" into the terminal or command prompt. Then run "npm install styled-components".
It worked just fine.

In my own case, The directory was

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\poop>
```

all I did was to add "cd me" in front of `PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\poop>`
because "me" was the name of my create-react-app project

after the above step, you now have `PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\poop\me>`

Then run `npm install styled-components`

it would work